# eigen spaces of similar matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

Suppose $A,B $ are similar matrices.Suppose $\alpha $ is an eigen value of $A$.Will the eigen space of $A$ with respect to $\alpha$ be the same as that of the eigen space of $B$ with respect to $\alpha$?If not will they have the same dimension?

Comment: No, they won't be the same, but they will have the same dimension.

Comment: How to prove they have same dimension

Comment: What does it mean for $A$ and $B$ to be similar?

Comment: $\exists $ a non singular matrix $P$ such that $B=PAP^{-1}$

Comment: Can you prove that $X$ is an eigenvector of $A$ if and only if $PX$ is an eigenvector for $B$, and that the eigenvalues are the same?

Answer (score 1):

Suppose $B = PAP^{-1}$, and let $E$ denote the eigenspace of $A$ associated with some $\alpha$.  We define
$$
P E = \{P x : x \in E\}
$$
Note that for all $y = Px \in PE$, we have
$$
By = PAP^{-1}(Px) = P(Ax) = \alpha Px = \alpha y
$$

Comment: Please explain how to conclude that both have same dimension here @Omnomnomnom sir

Comment: If you have a basis for one, how can you make a basis for the other?

Answer (score 0):

The answer is yes. Similar matrices are representation of the same linear operator in different bases. Eigenspaces corresponding to an eigenvalue are essentially (geometrically) the same but the eigenvector(s) have different coordinates in the new basis, e.g., $y=Px$ as in Omnomnomnom's answer.